# How do I setup Thinktecture Identity server v3 beta 1-2 with ASP.NET Identity?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity, thinktecture-ident-server

I have looked at all the docs for Thinktecture Identity server v3 and have not been able to figure out how to get started using ASP.NET identity.

Can someone please explain at a high level step by step from step 1 (i.e. cloning the git repo) to it's final state which is up and running with the Identity Manager as well. Essentially I just need to know how to set this up.

The videos I see on Vimeo seem out of date (and I may be wrong because I am new to this) because now there are several repositories and in the videos I think I saw the asp.net identity user service in the same solution in core.

I am trying to prototype this for my employer (AngularJS, Identity Server, OAuth 2.0, resource owner vs implicit flow, ) and am hoping to get this working as soon as possible.

Many thanks in advance!
Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked [Thinktecture.IdentityManager.AspNetIdentity](https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityManager.AspNetIdentity) solution? There is example how to configure it (see [Host](https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityManager.AspNetIdentity/tree/master/source/Host) project):

```
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var factory = new Thinktecture.IdentityManager.Host.AspNetIdentityIdentityManagerFactory("AspId");
        app.UseIdentityManager(new IdentityManagerConfiguration()
        {
            IdentityManagerFactory = factory.Create
        });
    }
```

In order to add this functionality to the clean project you just have to add necessary packages

```
  <package id="Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v3" version="1.0.0-beta1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v3.AspNetIdentity" version="1.0.0-beta1" targetFramework="net45" />
```

and configure it in the Startup. It's not necessary to clone git repo and compile it...